# Как исключить строки где встречается DLC между версией и годом? (Регулярные выражения)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Между версией и годом может быть абсолютно что угодно, или же может вообще ничего не быть, и неизвестно где там встретится слово DLC поэтому я использовал .* но из за этого, строки в которых встречается слово DLC не исключились...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете текст вместо картинки вставить? Кажется,  вам вместо `.*` нужно использовать `(?:(?!DLC).)*?`

Comment: \d+[.]\d+.*\(\d{4}\)\s(?:PC)?

Comment: Пасиб, вроде сработало... но я не понял почему, и как оно сработало)

Comment: Я объяснил в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209854/182013).

Comment: Я прочитал) и поставил плюс, но оно пишет что мой голос не отображается из за того что я новичок.

Comment: Всё, больше не новичкок :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```cs
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?:(?!DLC).)*?\((\d{4})\)(?:\s*PC)?
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Hhpf3j/2). Тут `.*` заменено конструкцией `(?:(?!DLC).)*`, т.е. так называемой "ограниченной точкой" (англ. "tempered dot", "tempered greedy token"). `.*` находит ноль и более (как можно больше) любых символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, тогда как `(?:(?!DLC).)*?` находит ноль и более повторов любого символа, отличного от символов перевода строки, как можно меньшее количество раз, который не является начальным символов подстроки `DLC`.

**Подробности**

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` - Подмаска №1: одна и более цифр, а затем ноль и более повторов точки + одной и более цифр
- `(?:(?!DLC).)*?` - любой текст, до первого вхождения `DLC`
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `(\d{4})` - Подмаска №2: четыре цифры
- `\)` - символ `)`
- `(?:\s*PC)?` - опциональная последовательность ноля и более пробельных символов, а затем `PC`.

Comment: Еще вопросик если можно)) А как сделать чтоб строка не захватывалась в случае если где-то после PC есть слово "Лицензия" например? (на примере того же правила)

Comment: @vihitar902 Наверное, `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?:(?!DLC).)*?\((\d{4})\)(?:\s*PC)?(?!.*Лицензия)`, см. [пример](https://regex101.com/r/Hhpf3j/3).

Comment: Супер!! спасибо!!!)